# I maybe corrupted my BIOS

Tags: boot, microsoft-windows

So the thing is that I was running a live elementary USB and wanted to use GParted to do some partitioning on my other USB but Gparted interrupted me constantly with the error that GPT table was missing (which I completely didn't know) and so I did as Gparted directed me and created a fake msdos table in my primary hard drive but after that on the next reboot the PC stopped working and directly started booting from the Realtek Network Agent via ipv4 and ipv6 (pics enclosed)  which should only be possible if there is a technical default with the hard drive or a windows failure. On failing to do so it redirected me to a new window that read " Default Boot Device Missing Or Boot Failed etc etc" (pic enclosed) The hard drive was fine (I opened up the laptop and checked that its completely fine) so I tried to reinstall my windows BUT THE REAL PROBLEM BEGING NOW!! My BIOS wont allow me to boot anymore from the disk drives. So I thought why not USB boot linux by the time but then the biggest shock came as I realised my BIOS wont let me boot from any external media and so I cant carry out any repair work. Any idea what went wrong?? Is my BIOS corrupted?? Also do tell me how to replace my BIOS as I am quite fed up with this one. Thanks is Advance

My specifications:--
Laptop name- Lenovo Z50-70 
Processor-Intel Core i5
Memory- 8 GB
Storage- 1 TB
Bios version- 9BCN25WW
Primary OS - Windows 10

Comment: Are you able to access the boot menu on startup? F12, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

On the side of the laptop there is a button next to the power button called a "NOVO" button. When the laptop is completely shut down, you can press that button and go straight into BIOS or UEFI depending on what type of motherboard your have installed. (They are basically the same with UEFI being the upgrade.)